# Detect New contact addition in contactList

Tags: android, contacts

I have to execute a peace of code on new contact found,So I'm using service to check whether new contact found in the ContactList.My question is-How can we get new contact added in ContactList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**
Create your own content observer and register it to detect any type of contact change

```
getApplication().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,new MyContentObserver());
```

**Step-2**
 Write your own logic to detect contact addition if new contact id is added.

Example:
Re-query a cursor to the Contacts table each time the ContentObserver changes and maintain the highest known CONTACT_ID value. The newly added contact will have the id which you have stored before

Comment: Hi,@Sunil Thanks for the reply,Can u plz elaborate it  ?

Comment: @Dipu Re-query a cursor to the Contacts table each time the ContentObserver changes and maintain the highest known CONTACT_ID value. The newly added contact will have the id which you have stored before

Comment: Hi @Sunil it's working Tell me one thing more how to get details of newly added contact?

Comment: @get all the contact ids which is greater than whatever you have stored and then write query to get contact details depending on the contact id